# Drawing a numbered triangle in c using loops

Tags: c, draw, shapes, triangle

I'm working on the first 2 parts (the ascending numbers and the spaces)
[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue7eJ.png)

this is how it's supposed to look like:

```
1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
  2 3 4 5 4 3 2
    3 4 5 4 3
      4 5 4
        5
```

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int N, i, j, M;

    do {
        printf("Entrez la valeur de N : ");
        scanf("%d", &N);
    } while (N <= 0 || N % 2 == 0);

    M = N;

    for (N = N; N >= 0; N--) {
        for (i = M; M - N > 0; i--)
            printf(" ");
        for (j = 1; j <= N; j++) {
            printf(" %d ", j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the code in the question, not a comment.

Comment: Also show the desired result as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it doesn't work"?

Comment: im having problems putting the code in the question

Comment: A source of confusion here `for (N = N; N >= 0; N--) {`

Comment: It's easy: Click [Edit] below the post, paste the code into the question, mark the code, then either push the code button {} or press Ctrl-K. Code markup is also useful for patterns like yours. I've done that for you.

Comment: i did it because i wanted to preserve N as N

Comment: thank uuuuu This is my first post thats why i didnt know to put code in there :")

Comment: That's okay, but it's also redundant. You can leave any of the three parts of the `for` blank. Or use an new variable to preserve `N` throughout.

Comment: @AssiaAlaoui It is important to have a variable name which really corresponds to what the variable is. For clarity.

Comment: i also did it because N gets subtracted every time and i wanted  the new value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is that the names of your variables introduce confusion.

In particular here, `for (i = M; M - N > 0; i--)` the condition `M-N > 0` introduces an infinite loop.

Everything becomes much simpler with better names selection.

Output

```
Entrez la valeur de N : 5
 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
   2 3 4 5 4 3 2
     3 4 5 4 3
       4 5 4
         5
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int N;

    do {
        printf("Entrez la valeur de N : ");
        scanf("%d", &N);
    } while (N <= 0 || N % 2 == 0);

    for (int row = 1; row <= N; ++row) {
        int n_blank = 2 * (row - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < n_blank; ++i)
            printf(" ");
        for (int j = row; j <= N; j++) {
            printf(" %d", j);
        }
        for (int j = N-1; j >= row; j--) {
            printf(" %d", j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```